# Fast way to check values of one dataframe against another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes.
df1:

```
                   Date     High      Mid      Low
1   2023-08-03 00:00:00  29249.8  29136.6  29152.3
4   2023-08-03 12:00:00  29395.8  29228.1  29105.0
10  2023-08-04 12:00:00  29305.2  29250.1  29137.1
13  2023-08-05 00:00:00  29099.9  29045.3  29073.0
18  2023-08-05 20:00:00  29061.6  29047.1  29044.0
..                  ...      ...      ...      ...
696 2023-11-26 20:00:00  37732.1  37469.9  37370.0
703 2023-11-28 00:00:00  37341.4  37138.2  37254.1
707 2023-11-28 16:00:00  38390.7  38137.2  37534.4
711 2023-11-29 08:00:00  38419.0  38136.3  38112.0
716 2023-11-30 04:00:00  38148.9  37800.1  38040.0
```

and df2:

```
                Start      Top   Bottom
0 2023-11-28 00:00:00  37341.4  37138.2
1 2023-11-24 12:00:00  38432.9  37894.4
```

I need to check if the values in the first dataframe fall within the range of the values in a row of a second dataframe and store the number of matches in a column. I can do it using iteration like this:

```
for idx in df1.index:

    df2.loc[
        (df2.Start !=  df1.at[idx, 'Date']) &
        (df2.Bottom < df1.at[idx, 'High']) &
        (df2.Top > df1.loc[idx, ['Mid', 'Low']].max()),
        'Match'] += 1
```

But this way is slow. Is there a faster way to do it without iteration?

Comment: Does df2 has always only two rows?

Comment: @gtomer No, it doesn't

Comment: [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) is quire fast - faster than a cross merge. However, your data is not easily reproducible. Kindly add a minimal dataset for df1 (without the ...) and also add the expected output dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have enough memory (depends on `df1` and `df2`), you can use a `cross merge`:

```
df2['Match'] = (df2.reset_index()
                   .merge(df1, how='cross')
                   .loc[lambda x:
                        (x.Start !=  x.Date) &
                        (x.Bottom < x.High) &
                        (x.Top > x[['Mid', 'Low']].max(axis=1))]
                   .value_counts('index').reindex(df2.index, fill_value=0))
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
                Start      Top   Bottom  Match
0 2023-11-28 00:00:00  37341.4  37138.2      0
1 2023-11-24 12:00:00  38432.9  37894.4      3
```